# Fedex Api - Can't get a customs form for Fedex Ground to Canada (from US)

Tags: fedex

I get an AUXILIARY_LABEL included in the response for all methods to Canada except from Ground. Any idea why not?

Answer (score 0):

The 'AUXILIARY_LABEL' which is an AWB (air waybill) only applies to the Express services. As such it's normal not to receive one within the XML response for the Ground service.